# Can we ask a similar questions about DNS VPN mechanisms & services?

Tags: discussion

[How do I securely store and manage 180 passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/432844/how-do-i-securely-store-and-manage-180-passwords)

The linked question revealed some great open source, free, freemium & paid ways to do manage passwords.

The intent is to be able to use sites & services that restrict access if outside a country or geographic region.

I travel out now and then and would like to avoid my access hampered.

I am sure lot of people benefited from the above question and same would be the case here.

What would be the best SE site to post it, if no SuperUser?

How should I frame this question, for better responses & avoid negatives / vote downs on SE?

Examples:

> - Cheapest/ Most economical DNS or VPN services that bypass geographic restrictions?
> - Cheapest/ Most economical services that help bypass geographic access restrictions?

and so on?

Thoughts?

Comment: A question asking for a list of services or any sort of question that ends in somebody recommending a VPN service wouldn't be on topic at Superuser.  There isn't a SE for that type of question honestly.

Answer (score 1):

The questions you want to ask are pretty hard to frame in such a way as to avoid a product or service reccomendation. These services may come and go, and are the sort of thing we *explicitly* target with the close reason that reads

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material
>   recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and
>   attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and
>   the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here
>   are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

I'm rather doubtful the question is askable here. Its pretty hard to frame this as a *process*, and geo-blocking restrictions are a bit of a cat and mouse game, especially when dealing with something like the great Chinese firewall.

Comment: If a password management question can be allowed why not a restriction bypassing mechanism? :) Kinda similar logic? 

I am not china restricted just when I am out of US and traveling then I need access and it bothers me. Can I pose a US specific question?

Comment: Process vs product. I must admit its a clever workaround for software recs being off topic here. If you wanted to run it *yourself* it may be a different. As is though, the question titles indicate to me a short, not quite so glorious end for your questions.

Comment: Its not a workaround.. Its a means to an end question. For the password thing also someone asked How to do X, and people gave great answers to that.. Its not even so much a software rec.. its a How to do X..

Comment: Plus it wont be a software rec.. cause those would be services using various mechanisms

Comment: It would be a service recommendation. I'm not sure any amount of verbal gymnastics would change that. If someone manages to do that here, I'd be *impressed*

Comment: @AlexS - Questions seeking recommendations on Hardware, Software, and Services are all not on topic.  They are all not on topic for one major reasons, they become outdated, and most recommendations are poorly written.

Comment: @Ramhound - Hmm.. 1. So what about the linked thread? 2. Should I post Software Rec SE site?

Comment: Its about a service tho, it do believe its out of the scope of SR.SE. Software recs not service recs

Comment: @AlexS - What about it?  You are asking if asking for a VPN service recommendation is on topic, it isn't, and I don't believe there to be a SE website where it is.